# VsCode debugging, testing and launching full-stack (NextJS, Python) app

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, testing, package.json, vscode-debugger

I'm developing a full-stack app using NextJS as frontend and Python FastAPI as backend, I'm investigating on the best way of launching, debugging and testing frontend and backend together.
The aim is to avoid having to launch frontend and backend separately from command line.

My code is structured in this way:

```
backend/
  server.py

frontend/
  package.json
  node_modules
  app

.vscode/
  launch.json
  settings.json
```

I thought that the best ways to launch backend and frontend together were using `.vscode` settings or `package.json` scripts.

I opted for using the `.vscode` to integrate also debugging and tests launching with VsCode but I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, also because it's IDE-related, is there a way to do it in some IDE-agnostic way?
Do you have any suggestions?

These are my `launch.json` and `settings.json` configurations:

launch.json

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Open App",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend"
    },
    {
      "name": "Python: FastAPI backend",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "uvicorn",
      "args": ["server:app", "--reload"],
      "jinja": true,
      "justMyCode": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/backend"
    },

  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
        "name": "Server/Client debug",
        "configurations": ["Next.js: debug server-side", "Python: FastAPI backend", "Open App"],
        "stopAll": true,
    }
  ]
}
```

settings.json

```json
{
  "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "-s",
    "./backend",
    "-p",
    "*_test.py"
  ],
  "python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/",
  "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
}
```

Is there something I can do better? Are there some useful tools I can use for debug and deploy my code?